# Downgrading OS X version from Mavericks to last OS upgrade?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I had an Application I used a lot with kids in my family that ran on the Power PC Mac. It was an interactive Alphabet program by the Learning Company with talking cartoon Characters.  2 through 5 year olds loved it. It was based on a 
Dr. Seuss's Book about the ABC's. Every letter was covered. The child could spend large amounts of time exploring each letter and little talking animations would come up. I upgraded my Mac laptop to Mavericks. Now the program will not work and there never was an upgrade of the program. How can I undo Mavericks and go back to the way my Mac used to be? I want that Power PC program back worse than an upgraded Mac.  Find me an ABC Program that Surpasses this Dr. Seuss program and I might reconsider downgrading. Can you please help me?

Comment: PowerPC support was dropped prior to Mavericks. What version of OS X were you running before you updated?

Answer (score 3):

The last Mac OS which supported `Power PC emulator (Rosetta)` on `x86` was `Snow Leopard`. You can back up your data using `Time Machine`, find distributive on your CD and install it.

**UPDATE**

As people said, you should copy your data directly without using `Time Machine`.

Comment: BTW, I don't know if Time machine internal format has been changed since 10.6

Comment: I don't believe it has been changed significantly anyway. I've been backing up a 10.6.8 and a 10.9.3 machine on the same disk for a while now. Each backup is made to practically stand on its own using hardlinks, so there shouldn't be a problem. Also, if necessary, it might be better to restore from a clean install of Mavericks anyway.

Comment: You cannot restore a Mavericks Time Machine backup to Snow Leopard. See my response below.

Comment: Thank you! I really didn't know about TM format, because I don't plan to downgrade and store backups not only with TM

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution: you may be able to run Snow Leopard in a virtual machine. A quick Google shows that running Snow Leopard in Parallels under Mavericks should be possible. [Here's the first link I found](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?294155-How-to-install-Snow-Leopard-Server-in-Parallels-9-under-Mavericks), for example.

Answer (score 0):

First, a sidenote, but of importance: **You [cannot](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3351) restore a Time Machine backup from Mavericks to Snow Leopard. You need to back up your data in a different manner before rolling the OSX back.**

With the risk of providing an answer which is both brief and externally linked, there is an excellent user tip from an ASC member for [**how to revert OS X back from Mavericks.**](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6161) This guide *includes reverting back to Snow Leopard directly from Mavericks*, which is what you're looking for. It's clear, detailed, and exactly the type of step-by-step guide I advise following.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue - tried 10.8 on an 2010 MBP. In the end, I had to re-install the older OS, because Apple does not see that any user should ever want to go back from the latest version.

If you have an external USB volume, either put the new system on that and install 10.6 on the PB (note: You must manually select Rosetta, by default it will not be installed!), or install 10.6 on the USB. Use the Control Panel "Start volume" to select which to boot from.

10.6.8 has become Apple's Windows XP. There are lots of good reasons not to upgrade.

Comment: It's not just Apple - most software has no downgrade path because it's not possible. New software can understand (and upgrade) the various settings of the old software, but nothing can understand settings which have not been developed yet.

Comment: 10.6.8: This is off topic. Besides, there might be some reasons to stick to legacy software, but there is NO excuse for it.

Comment: Apple is not a religion, and you don't have to believe in what they say. Sometimes it is better to use your own judgement. Try it - you will be surprised!

Comment: Even more off topic: Actually, that's wrong. But using legacy software is security risk, even if it still has support, it won't last as long as support for current OS releases. Additionally, you might want community support, which is easier to get if you use a current OS as most others do.

Comment: The question is about a learning game for children - nobody said that he wants to go online with that. Please, please switch on your brain before posting FUD.

Comment: If you would both like a chat room to work out the question, I can set one up in private. Please do try to not characterize people or use pejorative terms like "fan boy" and instead critique posts with some amount of respect for those who appear to have a different priority than you. My quess is you're both in agreement about the answer - just that you're not clear on the use case yet.